# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= }

Tags: android, android-intent

I am attempting to launch an intent to open link in android browser.

I have populated listview with XML pull parser which contains url for every single item.

Weird part is that first few items works fine, and it takes me to download link, but items below won't work and it crashes on click.

```
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String url = worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPopulation();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));

            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Logcat Error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
    at Search.ListViewAdapter$1.onClick(ListViewAdapter.java:95)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:

Here is my SerachActivity.java

```
public class SearchActivity extends Fragment {
    // Declare Variables
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    static String RATINGPOINTS = "ratingPoints";
    static String APPHEADLINE = "appHeadline";
    static String STOREURL = "storeURL";
    static String ICONURL = "iconUrl";
    EditText editsearch;
    private List<mobAppModel> worldpopulationlist = null;

    @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("mobAppModel", "OnCreate()");    
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_main, container, false);

        // Execute DownloadXML AsyncTask
        new DownloadXML().execute();
        return rootView; }

    // DownloadXML AsyncTask
    private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            // Set progressdialog title
//          mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
//          // Set progressdialog message
//          mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//          mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//          // Show progressdialog
//          mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<mobAppModel>();
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            // Retrive nodes from the given website URL in XMLParser.class
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/te0c0s7y7zr79tm/kategorijeXML.xml");
            // Retrive DOM element
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

            try {
                // Locate the NodeList name
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("appInfo");
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    mobAppModel map = new mobAppModel();
                    map.setRank(parser.getValue(e, RATINGPOINTS));
                    map.setCountry(parser.getValue(e, APPHEADLINE));
                    map.setPopulation(parser.getValue(e, STOREURL));
                    map.setFlag(parser.getValue(e, ICONURL));

                    worldpopulationlist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                    worldpopulationlist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
            editsearch = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.search);

            // Capture Text in EditText
            editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
                            .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    adapter.filter(text);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ListViewAdapter where intent is located:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private List<mobAppModel> worldpopulationlist = null;
    private ArrayList<mobAppModel> arraylist;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            List<mobAppModel> worldpopulationlist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<mobAppModel>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView ocjena;
        TextView naziv;
        TextView developer;
        ImageView iconUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return worldpopulationlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);  
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.ocjena = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ocjena);
            holder.naziv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.naziv);
            holder.developer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.developer);
            // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
            holder.iconUrl = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iconUrl); 
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.ocjena.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getRank());
        holder.naziv.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getCountry());
        holder.developer.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position)
                .getPopulation());
        // Set the results into ImageView
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getFlag(),
                holder.iconUrl);
        // Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String url = worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPopulation();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ListViewAdapter.class);
                i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));

                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        worldpopulationlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (mobAppModel wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

SS:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the URL for the later elements is empty. Show the code where you are populating the views with the URLs. Also, where are you setting the value of the variable `position` that is used in the `onClick()` method? Basically we need more context.

Comment: There, you can see it now.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set an `onClickListener` for each item in your list. This is very inefficient. Instead, you should set an `onItemClickListener` on your `ListView` in the activity. When an item is clicked, this method will be called with the position in the list that was clicked.

Comment: Yes I tried that already, but I'm getting an error that `The method setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type View`

Comment: You call `setOnItemClickListener()` on a `ListView`. If you've cast the `View` to a `ListView` (which you have in your code), then it is fine.

Comment: Oh I understand, I tried it now in my SearchActivity.java, but there is no difference. Again same thing. First items are ok and opening, and items below won't work, crashes...

`listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
   
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{         
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) 
{          
String url = worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPopulation();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);        
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);          
}   
});`

Comment: Well then I'm guessing that the call to `worldpopulationlist.get(position).getPopulation()` is returning null. Please add some debug logging or step through it with a debugger.